# Carrierwave; overwrite 'thumb' method to have standard thumbs for non-image assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a thumb version of my image assets:

```
version :thumb, :if => :image? do
  process :resize_to_fill => [118, 100]
end
```

Now I get a RoutingError for my non-image assets. I tried hacking a thumb method in AssetUploader.rb:

```
def thumb
  if has_image_extension?(file.original_filename)
    super
  else
    "/assets/file_types/#{extension(file.original_filename)}.jpg"
  end
end
```

This generates an error (NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `thumb'), which makes sense.

Is there a nicer way of fixing this than making a thumb_url method in the Asset model?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `version` is a method of an instance of a CarrierWave class. The first argument should be a symbol which will be appended as a string to the saved filename.

However the `:if` symbol recieves a method name ( which needs to be implemented ) for deciding if the version should be created.

The question is how is your `:image?` method implemented!

I've got a naive implementation of it, here:

```
def image?( new_file )
  # TODO FIXME wrong way to check for image
  new_file.content_type.include?('image') && 
  !new_file.content_type.include?('photoshop') && 
  !new_file.content_type.include?('svg')
end
```